# Disable Jenkins autostart on OS X

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have a prototyping instance of Jenkins (most recent version) on my local machine (OS X 10.10). It starts every time I boot my machine.

How can I disable this autostart?

I want to start it manually only when I need it.

Comment: Is it started through `launchd`? You can probably check with `sudo launchctl list| grep -i jenkins` or `sudo launchctl list | more`

Comment: Yes it is. I unloaded it with `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` and removed the file afterwards. However, after reboot, file is still there and Jenkins is running again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All right, have it sorted now. `launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` did the trick. Jenkins is no longer running after reboot. `-w` option was the key.

Comment: It did not work, error message "Could not find specified service". Maybe I have a newer version of Jenkins. My OS is Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

**automatictester** is 99% right.

The only missing step is that since jenkins runs as a *system* service (at least on my machine), you'll need to use:

`sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

Comment: I got `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist: No such file or directory`. Has the plist file moved to other location?